# Pug templating incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firefox, pug

My pug code is like this, with linkPreface and val as passed values. I am using express on nodeJs.

```
p #{ linkPreface }

each val in files
    -var url=linkPreface+val
    p #{url}
    a(href=`${url}`) #{val} </br>
```

For the link part, the HTML is

```
<a href="http:/localhost:3000/folder/files">files</a>
```

For some reason whenever I click on or mouse over the link, I get http://localhost:3000/localhost:3000/folder/files, repeating the localhost:3000 part, which makes the link worthless. I am running this on Firefox. Any ideas how this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `linkPreface` and try like this,

```
p #{ linkPreface }

each val in files
    -var url=val
    p #{url}
    a(href=`${url}`) #{val} </br>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I am still having a problem. The main issue I am finding is that pug is repeating elements of the url path, which makes the url that is created to be incorrect. Very frustrating when I am passing the right information to pug, but it messes it up.